# Eucledian norm of unity with angle $\lambda$

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to know what the angle means,

Consider the unit interval $[0;1]$ together with the $L_2$ norm:

$$\|f\|_2 = \sqrt{\int_0^1 f^2(x) dx} $$

Consider $\ f=a + bx $ as the "unit circle" $\|f\|_{2}$ = $\ 1 $ with angle  $\lambda$.

Comment: You're question is not understandable as it is currently written.  I'm having a hard time guessing what you could even be trying to ask here

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a norm and an inner product, you can define the angle by

$ \cos \theta = \frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{|x||y|} $

You can do this in a Hilbert space where an inner product is defined.